# hover event inside on function in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
  thumbnail.on('click', data, click_pressed);
  function click_pressed(info) {
        var details_shower = $(".details-showers");
        details_shower.empty();
        details_shower.css("display", "table");
        details_shower.append(
            $("<img>").attr("src", info.data.movies[info.target.id].posters.detailed),
            $("<h3>").text(info.data.movies[info.target.id].title)
            );
    }
```

This works great. But how can I do it for hover event?

```
 thumbnail.on('hover', data, click_pressed);
```

This doesn't seem to work. I know it requires two functions, one for mouseenter and one for mouseleave. Can anyone post an example?

- Thanks

Comment: when the mouse leaves the element what do you want to do.. do you want to reset the values in `details-showers`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) is not an event, use [mouseenter](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/). [hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) is a utility method to register both [mouseenter](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) and [mouseleave](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) handlers

```
thumbnail.on('mouseenter', data, click_pressed);
```

---

If you want to reset the `details-showers` element when the mouse leaves then

```
thumbnail.on('mouseenter', data, click_pressed).on('mouseleave', data, function(){
    $(".details-showers").empty()
});
```

Comment: @downvoter did I miss anything... hover is a helper method not an event is that understanding wrong

Comment: Hmm... it might be useful to do something on mouseleave, too. I'm wondering if that's the downvote reason.